# Inheritance exception on exist exception

Tags: c#, oop, exception, inheritance

I have some functions that throw exceptions. I want that the code block that catch them also throw exception based on the exception that throw but with more parameters like ID and Note. how can I do that?

If any one can give me even direction it will be good!

Thanks (sorry for my English...)

Example for what I want (I know is not valid code...)

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogException l=e;
    l.Note = "note...";
    l.ID = 12;
    throw l;
}
```

Comment: Build a "State" class that contains all the parameters.  Then pass the class   to the exception handler.  The variable 'e' can contain a class.

Comment: Why not just throw a `LogException` in the first instance?

Comment: @DarrenYoung Is not my code that always throw the exception, because of that I don't have complete control on the exception type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
try
{
    //....kaboom
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var newEX= new Exception("custom message", ex);
    newEX.Data.Add("any key",  "any obj");
    throw newEX;
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer, apart from the fact that you should create your own exception type rather than throwing Exception. And you may want to write your own top level handler that recursively goes through all inner exceptions and compiles a pretty list of all messages and stack traces to be logged. You should not call it LogException, the exception name should tell something about the problem, not about what you may want to do with it when you catch it.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to define your own exception (inherited from Exception) that had those extra properties. See here for the basic format a custom exception should take
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229064(v=vs.100).aspx
(Note that you should make the exception serializable.) you just add your extra properties.

Once you have created the exception class (LogException in your case) then your above code will work.